# Can't change display property with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, image

I'm trying to get an object (embedded twitch stream) to show when an image is clicked. Everything seems to be working fine except when I try to changed its display property. It is set to `display: none;` by default and it is supposed to change to `display: block;` when it is clicked.

HTML

```
<object id="twitchStream" class="center" .... </object>
<a href="#" onClick="showDiv()"><img class="center" src="img/hsl_arrow.png" /></a>
```

CSS

```
#twitchStream{
    display: none;
}

object.center{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 620px;
}
```

JavaScript

```
function showDiv() {
    document.getElementById('twitchStream').style.display = "block";
}
```

**EDIT**

Object's Contents

```
<object id="twitchStream" class="center" 
type="application/x-shockwave-flash" height="378" 
width="620" id="live_embed_player_flash" data="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/
live_embed_player.swf?channel=hsstarleague" bgcolor="#000000"><param 
name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" /><param name="allowNetworking" value="all" />
<param name="movie" value="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf" />
<param name="flashvars" value="hostname=www.twitch.tv&channel=hsstarleague&auto_play=true&start_volume=25" /></object>
```

I'm so sorry for the formatting, I copied and pasted it and was having some trouble.

Comment: Have you thought about using jQuery? It makes these kinds of things much easier to do.

Comment: Consider setting the display property to "" (empty string) and not "block".

Comment: Since the element is not actually a div I'd recommend renaming it. As @RobG noted setting an empty string (thus restoring the default visible display) may likely be the answer.

Comment: For this specific task you don't need jQuery since what you're trying to do should work for all browsers way back to IE5. One thing I recommend you doing though is a bit of defensive programming - assign the result of `getElementById` to a var and then check if it really exists before setting the display attribute.

Comment: What is the content of the object? An object element by itself is not necessarily a visible element, it's a [replaced element](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/conform.html#replaced-element) that is outside the scope of CSS and style rules. E.g. image elements are replaced by the image, the element's attributes are applied to the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, objects should be styleable with css attributes. But objects like flash and java applets are drawn by their respective code and sometimes the browser doesn't have much control over it.

One solution is to put your object in a div of its own and then hide that div. This trick has been known to be very reliable and should work for flash:

```
<div id="twitchStream">
    <object id="twitchStreamObject">...</object>
</div>
```

Now your code should work as written.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing your JavaScript code with the following:

```
window.showDiv = function() {
  document.getElementById('twitchStream').style.display = "block";
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3rCHJ/.

P.S. Please don't do this in production - polluting global namespace is very, very bad.

Comment: then change `window.showDiv` to `var showDiv`(inside the `HEAD`), but both are global?

Comment: exactly, this variable is going to be global either way, so what is the point of your comment?

Comment: just a punctuation bug... :D

Comment: The OP has already declared the function using a function declaration, changing that to a function expression and assignment makes no difference what so ever to the code.

Comment: is there a way to do this without the global variable? Sorry if I'm sounding dumb, I've just got into web development stuff and if "polluting global namespace" is bad, I feel like there is a better way.

Comment: @JacobGreenway—yes (wrap the function body in an IIFE), but that's irrelevant. It's setting the value (and perhaps the expected result) that the OP has issues with.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't mind using jQuery here is a simple solution

```
function showDiv(){
   $('#twitchStream').show();
};
```

Comment: What will the resulting value of the display property be then?

Comment: Ok, I might try that, although I'd prefer just doing it in vanilla javascript. Also, do I need to download JQuery libraries to use it? Or can I import it through the web?

Comment: @RobG the css value will equal display = block

Comment: @JacobGreenway you don't need to download it Google has hosted libraries here is the jquery                                    https://developers.googlQ.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery             
I usually just use the downloadable jQuery library when I'm writing code on my localhost but when I put the website live I use a hosted library like Google's

Comment: @swsa—so how is that any different to what the OP is doing already? Other than requiring 4,000 lines of code that aren't currently in the page.

Comment: @RobG not different at all just simpler that's all

Comment: So "here's another way to do what you are already doing that you've told us doesn't work"?

Comment: Yaaa, I tried it, I do like jQuery, but ya, it's still not working. :/

Comment: @swsa—did you read the OP's comment? "I tried it, I do like jQuery, but ya, it's still not working". The problem is that setting display to block **doesn't work for the OP's object**. How you set it is irrelevant.

Comment: @RobG chilln well since you know so much why don't you uhhhh come up with an answer to his problem other than wasting everyone's time? food for thought

Comment: @swsa—glad you're comfortable. It's raining here, putting out bush fires so life is sweet. I have no answer (hence I haven't posted one) since I don't know what the content of the OP's object is.

Comment: I'll edit the OP with the object's content, one sec.